# Android 9-Patch Error

Tags: android, button

I am trying to create a 9-patch image but the text is not being accommodated correctly on the button.

[image]

the text should sit at the center of the button on Facebook login.

this is the original png

[image]

Tried this kinda 9patch

[image]

ended up like this

[image]

Button XML code:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/splash_facebook_button_selector"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/splash_facebook"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="8pt"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set gravity for your button:

```
Button signInBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signInBtn);
signInBtn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); //or Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL or any other you need
```

Comment: i tried that by adding android:gravity="center" but still doesnt help :(

Comment: that's strange. are you sure you tried `android:gravity`, not `android:layout_gravity` ?

Comment: i have both the properties.. layout also since i need it center aligned

Comment: so i've just tried it on emulator and it works (http://goo.gl/BfL2c). if you are sure your xml is correct, my only guess is your text for the button contains new line ("\n") at the end. I tried this with your original .9.png

Comment: thanks.. if u observe the corners are rounded in the image.. but when i use this i get a rectangle image. i read some where that adding a 0 padding did the trick and it did.